# Replace specified strings in file with strings from other file with sed

Tags: sed, files, replace

I have two files like this.

file1

```
line 1
line 2
... (more lines)
aaa PLACEHOLDER bbb ccc
... (more lines)
ddd PLACEHOLDER eee fff
... (more lines)
etc
```

file2

```
NEWTEXT1
NEWTEXT2
... (more lines)
```

There are always the same number of NEWTEXT strings in file2 as there are lines with PLACEHOLDER in file1. I don't know which lines the PLACEHOLDER strings are on in file1 and the number of PLACEHOLDER strings can vary with different sets of files file1 and file2.

I want to replace each PLACEHOLDER with the corresponding string in file
2. So for this example the new file would be

```
line 1
line 2
... (more lines)
aaa NEWTEXT1 bbb ccc
... (more lines)
ddd NEWTEXT2 eee fff
... (more lines)
etc
```

Is this possible with sed thanks.

Comment: See also: [Easiest way to find/replace in a file using a list?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/55535)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use the `GNU sed` stream editor and place one newtext line from file2 underneath the placeholder line and then join them in the next invocation of sed:-

```
sed -e '/PLACEHOLDER/R file2' file1 |
sed -Ee '
  /PLACEHOLDER/N
  s/PLACEHOLDER(.*)\n(.*)/\2\1/
'  -
```

---

Result:-

```
line 1
line 2
... (more lines)
aaa NEWTEXT1 bbb ccc
... (more lines)
ddd NEWTEXT2 eee fff
... (more lines)
etc
```

---

The one-line version of the above:

```
$ sed -e '/PLACEHOLDER/R file2' file1 | sed -Ee '/PLACEHOLDER/N;s/PLACEHOLDER(.*)\n(.*)/\2\1/' -
```

Comment: excellent, works great thanks. can you please explain the second sed command - why use -E and /N thanks. is it possible to combine all these commands in 1 line.

Comment: We use the -E ,standing for, extended regex support. It is because of this support that we are able to use capturing parentheses w/o escaping them thus contributing to readability and to prevent backslashitis. Yes see the edits for piling everything into a single line.

Comment: The /.../N is needed to stick the new text line with the placeholder line so that the placeholder string can be traded with the new text string. Remember, sed can only manipulate data in its pattern space.

Comment: excellent, thank you again.

Answer (score 2):

I'd use `perl`:

```
perl -pe '
  s{PLACEHOLDER}{
    $replacement = <STDIN>;
    chomp $replacement;
    $replacement
  }ge' file1 < file2
```

That also allows more than one `PLACEHOLDER` to be replaced per line.